# Getting data from one tomcat server to another tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, saiku

I am using saiku server for data analytics which is running in one tomcat and i run my spring boot application in another tomcat, i want to get data from saiku server to my spring boot application for generating chart (i.e) from one tomcat server to another tomcat server.i got error such as

here is my code for getting data from saiku to my springboot application

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-ng-hide=true>

var myClient = new SaikuClient({
    server: "http://localhost:8080/saiku",
    path: "/rest/saiku/embed",
    user: "admin",
    password: "admin"
});
myClient.execute({
    file: "/homes/home:admin/sample_reports/.saiku",
    htmlObject: "#saiku2",
    render: "chart",
    mode: "line",
    chartDefinition: {
            width: 560,
            colors: ['grey','red','blue'],
            extensionPoints: {
                    legend: true,
                    legendShape: 'circle',
                    legendSize: {width: '100%'},
                    legendLabel_textStyle: "#990000",
                    legendFont: 'normal 11px "Open Sans"'
            }
    },
    zoom: true
});
function displayChart(path, htmlDiv){
    myClient.execute({
        file: path,
        htmlObject: "#"+htmlDiv,
        render: "chart",
        mode: "line",
        chartDefinition: {
                width: 560,
                colors: ['grey','red','blue'],
                extensionPoints: {
                        legend: true,
                        legendShape: 'circle',
                        legendSize: {width: '100%'},
                        legendLabel_textStyle: "#990000",
                        legendFont: 'normal 11px "Open Sans"'
                }
        },
        zoom: true
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Hello world")
});
    $.get( "http://localhost:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/api/repository?type=saiku,sdb", function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        var response = (data);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            console.log("JSON ==>"+data[i].type);
            // get reports only under homes
            if(data[i].type=="FOLDER" && data[i].name=="homes"){
            console.log("data[i].repoObjects ==>"+data[i].repoObjects)
                // for file only we generate the saiku reports
                if(data[i].repoObjects && data[i].repoObjects.length>0){
                    console.log("i am inside"+data[i].repoObjects.length)
                    var arr = [];
                    arr = (data[i].repoObjects);
                    for (var k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
                        console.log("repo ==>"+arr[k].name);
                        if(arr[k].name=="home:admin"){
                            // retrieve all reports under home:admin folder
                            console.log("repo ==>"+JSON.stringify(arr[k].repoObjects[0].repoObjects));
                            // arr[k] is the home:admin folder. iterate all the files
                            for(var z=0;z<arr[k].repoObjects.length;z++){
                                // this is now the list of files and folders under homes/home:admin
                                if(arr[k].repoObjects[z]){
                                    var folderObjects =new Array(arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects);
                                    console.log(arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects.length)
                                    for(var x=0;x<arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects.length;x++){
                                        console.log(x)
                                        if(arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects[x]){
                                            console.log(arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects[x].path)
                                            displayChart(arr[k].repoObjects[z].repoObjects[x].path,"saiku"+x);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }                       


                        }

                    }
                }


            }
        }
    });



</script>
```

and my error is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/embed/export/saiku/json?formatter=fl…ned&file=%2Fhomes%2Fhome%3Aadmin%2Fsample_reports%2F.saiku&_=1470641532009. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401
```

Answer (score 2):

I never used Saiku server but maybe I can give you a general idea about why this error happens.

You should either disable Access-Control or implement it properly.

There is an extensive guide on correctly implementing the feature for Spring here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Also you should look up what is 'Cross origin resource sharing' and why it's needed here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

If your @SpringBootApplication class extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter then you can disable CORS like this:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
```

You can also disable CORS directly in Tomcat:
http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

But before doing this please read up on CORS and get an understanding of why it's needed and what's the consequences when you disable it.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @FrankerZ I'll build up in this just give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use saiku rest API for login. For example:

$.post( "http://localhost:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/session/", { username: "admin", password: "admin" } );

Check this:
https://groups.google.com/a/saiku.meteorite.bi/forum/#!msg/user/djic697fUbk/IPWlTyazAwAJ

I case saiku is running on other tomcat, you can use CorsFilter in the saiku tomcat web.xml

User Cors carefully...